# C# linq and expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to c# and I am having problem understanding the given problem statement.
Problem statement : 
Write a program to find the vehicles released between certain year.

1. class Vehicle is already given for your reference.
2. class Program contains a hard-coded list with vehicle information in the 'vehicleList' attribute.

a) Implement method 'getVehicleName'.

public static void getVehicleName(int fromYear, int toYear)          //method signature

This method must must display the vehicle names (from the given list) released between the fromYear and toYear (including these years).  USING LINQ CONCEPT

b) Implement method 'Main'.

Get the from year and to year from the user. Pass it to 'getVehicleName' method.

NOTE : NEED NOT call 'getMyExpression' method in Main.

c) Implement method 'getMyExpression'

public static Expression getMyExpression(int fromYear, int toYear)

This method snippet is already given for you. THIS METHOD IS FOR TESTING YOUR LINQ QUERY EXPRESSION OR LINQ METHOD EXTENSION.  So fill your query expression or method extension in the space holder provided. ONLY THE QUERY EXPRESSION OR METHOD EXTENSION.  Nothing more need to be implemented in this class.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include code as text, not images. Not all SO visitors will follow links to images and some can't because of corporate firewalls. Text also enables people to copy/paste in case they need to do their own testing and makes it searchable. Text lowers the barrier to providing you help.

Comment: What `getMyExpression` is for?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're almost there:

```
from v in vehicle 
where v.ReleaseYear >= fromYear && v.ReleaseYear <= toYear 
select v.VehicleName
```

alternatively do the same with method chain

```
vehicle.Where(v => v.ReleaseYear >= fromYear && v.ReleaseYear <= toYear)
.Select(n => n.VehicleName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe inherit List
Implement method `getVehicleName` as a linq query

```
public string getVehicleName => this.FirstOrDefault(o => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from v in vehicleList where v.ReleaseYear>=fromYear &&v.ReleaseYear<=toYear select n;
```

Comment: While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

While implementing *getVehicleName* use:

```
from v in vehicleList where v.ReleaseYear>=fromYear && v.ReleaseYear<=toYear 
select v.VehicleName;
```

And for method extension use:

```
vehicleList.Where(s=> s.ReleaseYear>=fromyear && s.ReleaseYear<=toYear).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vehicle.cs**

```
public class Vehicle          
{
    public String VehicleId{get; set; }
    public String VehicleName{ get; set; }
    public String Brand { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }

    public Vehicle(String vehicleId, String vehicleName, String brand,int releaseYear)
    {
        this.VehicleId = vehicleId;
        this.VehicleName = vehicleName;
        this.Brand = brand;
        this.ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
    }
    
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)   
    {
        
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter From Year :");
        int fromYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter To Year :");
        int toYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        GetVehicleName(fromYear,toYear);
     
        
        
    }
    public static void GetVehicleName(int fromYear , int toYear){
        var resultQuery = from v in VehicleList where v.ReleaseYear >= fromYear && v.ReleaseYear <= toYear orderby v.ReleaseYear select v;
        Console.WriteLine($"Vehicle Name Released Between {fromYear} And {toYear} :");
        foreach (Vehicle s in resultQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.VehicleName);

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        
        
    }
    public static ParameterExpression variableExpr = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerable<Vehicle>), "sampleVar");
    
    public static Expression GetMyExpression(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {  
        
        Expression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(variableExpr, Expression.Constant(from v in VehicleList where v.ReleaseYear >= fromYear && v.ReleaseYear <= toYear orderby v.ReleaseYear select v));
        return assignExpr;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.